# When 2 PC's are connected to the same switch I have no ethernet connection to either, but if 1 is connected the ethernet works

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

I just moved into my college dorm/room, I have an ethernet connection-point in the wall and have it connected to my 8-port switch that I have been using for over a year at home with multiple connection at once without any problems.

I have with me my Macbook and my stationary PC. Connecting to the ethernet using only my PC/Macbook and not the other works fine and the internet is working as intended, but once I plug in the other ethernet cable for the other device into the switch, neither of the networks work, and I have no internet on either of them.

- Both devices have different IPv6, IPv4 adresses
- They have the same subnet mask.
- There's no internet if I connect one of the cables to my PS4 either.

Differences on my PC and Macbook (when connected ALONE):

- IPv6 Address on PC end with :ff23::200 while mac ends with :ffe2::69
- IPv4 Address: 10.xxx.3.205 while mac ends with .2.208
- Subnet mask is the same on both 255.255.252.0
- Default gateway is the same, 10.xxx.0.1

When connected to both at the same time:

- My mac get an IP: 169.xxx.128.245
- PC get a Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 169.xxx.180.9
- Both Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0
- No default gateway
- My PC says its "Unidentified network" and "No Internet"
- My mac says "AX88x72A has a self-assigned IP-address and will not be able to connect to the internet"

UPDATE: I got some help from a "caretaker" or whatever since the administation was gone, and multiple people have had the same issue so its most likely some problem/restriction the admin has set. I took advice and bought a router and it helped my problem.

Comment: Have you compared notes with any if your dorm neighbors?  One possibility that comes to mind is that the campus network is limiting you to one device per wall jack.

Comment: @CharlesBurge 
No, I have not talked to anyone else yet, I had no idea you could limit the wall jack to only one device, that seems kinda weird if they had that. (and is there a way around that?)

Comment: it is possible that your switch is broken, but network management from upstream seems as likely. it is remotely possible that if you replaced the switch with a router it may see all your devices as one, but its just as likely they would be able to tell and deny you DHCP addresses (which is likely what is happening since the mac takes on a zero-conf 169. address). may just be best to ask the dorm administration.

Comment: @FrankThomas this does not sound like a switch fault.   I agree that it is likely upstream management and a router would most likely solve the problem.  I don't think they would be able to tell that a router was installed instead of a single device, particularly if you are able to program the MAC address on the WAN interface such that it does not look like one belonging to a company that specializes in routers.

Comment: @davidgo, Agreed. I'm probably just being reluctant to tell a college student to shell out for a router with the expectation that it will work. I know that routers can be detected by advanced fingerprinting techniques, and just taking a close look at the nature of the traffic would expose the presence of multiple hosts, but that takes substantial security infrastructure, and policies might be stringent or lenient. it all depends on how seriously the network admins are about this.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hello, I do see that multiple TP-Link router are being used on the network when I look into the Wifi list, I guess that would imply (from what i understand) that it most likely would work if I get my self a router and plug it into the wall? If that is a solution that could work I will definitely try this out.

Comment: Im contacting the administration here today, and will update if it's an intended feature they have added or if its a problem. If its still a problem I will try to get a router connected to see if it fixes the problem. Thanks for the help so far everyone!